# Masonry: What is the purpose of columnWidth property?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-masonry, masonry, column-width

When we are defining a masonry layout, we need to specify the **columnWidth** property in javascript like this:

```
$maincontent.masonry({
    columnWidth: 200,
    itemSelector: '.hentry',
    isFitWidth: true,
    isAnimated: true
});
```

And then in CSS, we define the width of columns anyways. So lets say for my css for the masonry column, I have a width definition like this:

```
#main article {
    margin: 0 20px 35px;
    width: 360px; /* Here I can give a width different than what I specified in javascript above */
    float: left;
}
```

And the masonry layout still kicks in, and uses the width I specified in css. So I dont understand, what is the purpose of specifying the width in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

All options are optional, but `columnWidth` and `itemSelector` are recommended.
If `columnWidth` is not set, Masonry will use the outer width of the first element.

you can even define them inside the `div` tag using `data-masonry-options` :

```
<div id="container" class="js-masonry"
  data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": ".item" }'>
```

instead of your `Jquery` code try to change the `columnWidth` using `data-masonry-options` and you will notice the difference here is a **[LIVE DEMO](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/osFxj)**

Or Correct your `Jquery` code it must be like so :

```
$('#maincontent').masonry({   // <---- instead of $maincontent.masonry
    columnWidth: 200,
    itemSelector: '.hentry',
    isFitWidth: true,
    isAnimated: true
});
```

if `maincontent` is a class use this selector instead `$('.maincontent')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What If the columnWidth value that I define in javascript is different than the width value that I define in css? I have tried that in the code snippet I posed above in my question. And it still works, and I see that the css width value is applied. The javascript columnWidth value is not applied. So what exactly does that mean?

Comment: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/osFxj play around the width in this example and you can see the deference

Comment: actualy the problem is in your code the way you are implementing the with in your js file is false

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The code snippet that I posted above is just a small part of the code I am using. I am sorry, I should have specified that **I was caching $('#maincontent') into a variable  called $maincontent**. This question was very specific to the property **columnWidth**. My actual code and problem can be seen here in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757981/at-a-certain-breakpoint-the-content-from-2-masonry-containers-on-the-same-page

Comment: i answered about the columnWidth , and i leaved an example to notice the deference please check this link http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/osFxj,